# How to get the JSON data in my app

Tags: ios, api, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

So , I want to make an app that calls the API of forecast.io to get weather in my app. Someone said me to use SwiftyJSON and Alamofire . I'm new to programming and this is my first app so i dont really know how to do it right. That's my code for now , but I don't know if it is right or not , it works but the call isn't made and I need to enter the JSON data to get the "temperature" data:

```
        // Get Weather
    let URL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/apikey/\(lat),\(long)"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { response in
            let jsonData: AnyObject?
            do {
                jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response.data!, options: [])
            } catch  {





            }

    }
```

It only says that "jsonData" was never used. That's all i wrote for getting the call.

Comment: What's the issue that you are facing with this? Can you be a little clearer?

Comment: I don't know how to enter in JSON to get data like "temperature" , like the syntax I have to enter in "catch"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the `jsonData` variable, you can use it like a regular `NSDictionary` by putting the following lines in the `do` block after the first line

```
guard let jsonDict = jsonData as? NSDictionary else {return}
```

If you want to get the current forecast, all you have to do is

```
guard let currentForecast = jsonDict["currently"] as? NSDictionary else {return}
```

And then you can get its properties using [this link](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2#data-points)

```
guard let temperature = currentForecast["apparentTemperature"] as? Int else {return}
```

All in all, your code should look something like this

```
let URL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/apikey/\(lat),\(long)"
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: nil)
    .responseJSON { response in
        let jsonData: AnyObject?
        do {
            jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response.data!, options: [])
            guard let jsonDict = jsonData as? NSDictionary else {return}
            guard let currentForecast = jsonDict["currently"] as? NSDictionary else {return}
            guard let temperature = currentForecast["apparentTemperature"] as? Int else {return}
            print(temperature)
        } catch  {
            //TODO: Handle errors
        }
}
```

The catch block is to handle errors, so if it could not parse the JSON that's where you would display an alert saying that there was an error.

Comment: Why the use of `as!`?  They can certainly be `nul`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I was just explaining how it works so it is clear to the OP. I'll just update the answer though.

Comment: So my code should look like this:
    '  do {
                    jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response.data!, options: [])
                    guard let jsonDict = jsonData as? NSDictionary else {return}
                    let currentForecast = jsonDict["currently"] as! NSDictionary
                    let temperature = currentForecast["apparentTemperature"] as! Int
                } catch  {
                    // TODO: handle errors
                }  
        } ' 
@kabiroberai

Comment: @perteadrian yup. Btw check out my updated answer, as it is a bit safer

Comment: Thank's a lot @kabiroberai !!

Comment: No problem @perteadrian :)

Comment: @perteadrian Btw it's possible to do this without Alamofire using `NSURLSession`. You can look it up, or if you want I could update my answer.

Comment: One more thing , if I want to get that data and put it on my label "temperatureLabel" I do so :
    **temperatureLabel.text = "\(temperature)º"**
but the xcode says to put "self."in front of my "temperatureLabel" and if I do so , i doesn't work . What i shold do to get that data in my label?
@kabiroberai

Comment: @perteadrian are you sure that you tried `self.temperatureLabel.text`?

Comment: @perteadrian I might know what your problem is. I'll just update my answer. See if it works once I do.

Comment: forget it ,i'm such an idiot ...  I handle it @kabiroberai , Thank's again.

Comment: @perteadrian no problem again :)